# Null Check Increasing cognitive complexity in code

Tags: java

Consider the POJO as below:

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private UserProperties properties;

    //getters, stetters, etc
}

class Adddress {
    private String state;
    private Street street;
    private String country;
}

class Street { 
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
}

class PersonAttributes {
    private String nationality;
    private String age;
}
```

So the scenario is this:

1. I do not have control over the POJO, it is a predefined structure.
2. Any of the fields can be null.
3. It is just a sample, the actual POJO is much more complex and nested.

When I query the field I have to add a null check to prevent null pointer exception.

For example:

```
if (person.getAddress() != null) {
     //do an operation on address

     if (person.getAddress().getStreet() != null) {
         //do operation on street
     }
}
```

Similarly for attributes and other nested fields.

Is there any alternative to the above approach that will reduce the complexity and avoid all these null checks?

I am fetching all the fields form a REST API and using Jackson to assign it to a POJO.

Is this approach correct for a highly nested JSON structure or there are other options which I should be using?

Comment: @Jens but in my scenario, the objects can be null, for example the address can be null or it cannot be null. if it is not null then it is used, else it is ignored. I need not throw an exception if it is null. I was looking for a way to reduce these checks if possible.

Comment: No there is no way that does not increase the complexity, because you always need an if statement which increase the complexity. The only why i see is to return an empty object insted of null. For instance an empty string for street.

Comment: I think you can't do anything else here. The fields being nullable and you not being able to change the structure inherently leads to such null checks. Of cource you can make it look "smarter" with ```Optional``` or whatever but you can't avoid the check for null itself.

Comment: If you where using kotlin the `?.` operator would help, but afaik there is no good pure java solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you cannot avoid the null checks.

You can 'beautify' them a bit:

```
import static java.util.Objects.*;

…

if( nonNull( person.getAddress ) )
{
    if( nonNull( person.getAdddress().getStreet() ) )
    {
        …
    }
}
```

You can introduce getters for the fields in the deeper nested elements on the top level elements:

```
class Person
{
    …

    public String getStreet()
    {
          var address = getAddress();
          var retValue = isNull( address ) ? null : address.getStreet();
          return retValue;
    }
}

…

if( nonNull( person.getStreet() ) )
{
    …
}
```

This can reduce the clutter of the top level code a bit.

If you are allowed to change the return types for your getters, using `java.util.Optional` could be an option, too:

```
class Person
{
    …

    public Optional<Address> getAddress()
    {
          return Optional.ofNullable( address );
    }

    public Optional<String> getStreet()
    {
          var retValue = getAddress().map( a -> getStreet() );
          return retValue;
    }
}

…

if( person.getStreet().isPresent() )
{
    …
}
```

But as said, the logic remains basically the same, it just looks differently.